# Call Action From view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my action :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddDispo(string idv, string dd, string df)
    {
        try
        {
            Models.indisponible model = new Models.indisponible();
            model.Dd = Convert.ToDateTime(dd);
            model.Df = Convert.ToDateTime(df);
            model.idv = idv;
            entity.indisponible.AddObject(model);
            entity.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Resultat"] = "La nouvelle date a été ajouté courrectement";
            return RedirectToAction("Dispo", "Agence", new { idv = idv});
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            TempData["Resultat"] = "Une erreur se produiset Vielliez ressaiyer";
            return RedirectToAction("Dispo", "Agence", new { idv = idv});
        }

    }
```

I want to call this action without using `Html.beginForm` from my view, i have made this trial but it hasn't worked :

```
<%: Html.Action("Accepter", "Adddispo", new { id = Model.idv, dd = Model.Dd, df = Model.Df  })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Action method is of type **HTTPOST**. So you need a form posting for that action to get invoked.  If you do not wish to use the form tag in your view, you may use jQuery to do a POST.

The below example does a post when user clicks on a button woth ID `btnPost`.

**HTML ( Content of Your View)**

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     Name : <input type="text" id="txtName" />  <br/>
     Age: <input type="text" id="txtAge" />  <br/>
     Place : <input type="text" id="txtPlace" />  <br/>
     <input type="button" value="Save" id="btnPost" /> 

     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){

         $("#btnPost").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // preventing the default button submit behaviour

            var name=$("#txtName").val();  //reading the text box values
            var age=$("#txtAge").val(); 
            var place=$("#txtPlace").val(); 

            $.post("YourController/AddDispo", { idv :name, dd : age, df=place} ,function(data) { 
              //Do whatever with the the response. may be an alert
              alert(data);
            });    
         });

     });
    </script>
```

**What it does**

**1)** In the head section of the document, we included the reference to the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/). I am including a reference from the google CDN. You may change that to include your local copy. If you are working with ASP.NET MVC, the default project template has this under the `Scripts` folder(version number may be different).

**2)** In the document [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event (`$(function(){..`) we are binding some functionality to the button which has an ID `btnPost`. We are binding the functionality on the `click` event. So whenever user clicks on that button, that piece of code will be executed.

**3)** We are reading the text box values, and making use of the [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method of jQuery. It will post the data we are passing ( we are passing the values of text boxes here) to the action method. once the action method returns something back to the calle, it will be stored in the data variable. you can do further things (show some message to user/ reload some content) after checking the value of that.

Comment: I get the point but can you give me an exmple because i'm nweebie in Jquery.

Comment: @Chlebta : see my updated answer. try reading jquery docs. It is an awesome library

Answer (score 0):

Action link will always send a "GET" request. Either remove that [HttpPost] attribute from your controller action, or use a similar technique suggested by shyju. Action link has some issues with windows events, so you should stick to stylized buttons unless there is specific need for anchors. A sample styling will be :

```
#mybutton input[type=submit] {
    background: none;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;        // to make it look like link
    border: none;           //     --- " -----
}
```